# Checkbox making several fields required

Tags: validation-rule, configuration

I want to make a workflow that when a Checkbox is true several fields will be required. But when i check the syntax, it says there is an extra ISBLANK field. Does anyone know why?

```
AND(Submitted_SDM_REVIEW__c  = TRUE , OR( ISBLANK(TEXT(Cyber_Security_Business_Impact__c)), ISBLANK(Engagement__c )),
ISBLANK(Text(Initial_AppSec_Applicability__c )),
ISBLANK(Text(Initial_CI_Applicability__c))) 
ISBLANK(TEXT( Initial_CI_HIPAA_Inherent_Risk__c )),
ISBLANK(Text(Initial_Overall_TRO_Risk__c )),
ISBLANK(Text(Initial_CI_PCI_Inherent_Risk__c )),
ISBLANK(Text(Initial_Red_Team_Applicability__c)),
ISBLANK(Text(Initial_Security_Arch_Applicability__c)),
ISBLANK(Text(Initial_Vendor_Applicability__c )),
ISBLANK(Text(Initial_Vendor_Inherent_Risk__c )),
ISBLANK(Project__c )), 
ISBLANK(Text(Project__r.BE_Alignment__c )),
ISBLANK(Project__r.BE_Conclusion__c )),
ISBLANK(Text(Project__r.BE_Team__c )),
ISBLANK(Project__r.Engagement__c )),
ISBLANK(Text(Project__r.Following_SDLC__c )),
ISBLANK(Project__r.Need_By_Date__c)),
ISBLANK(Text(Project__r.Pilot_or_Poc__c )),
ISBLANK(Project__r.Project_Description__c)),
ISBLANK(Project__r.Project_Expected_Go_Live_Date__c)),
ISBLANK(Project__r.Project_Manager__c )),
ISBLANK(Project__r.Regions__c )),
ISBLANK(Project__r.Requestor__c )))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
AND(
    Submitted_SDM_REVIEW__c  = TRUE , 
    OR( ISBLANK(TEXT(Cyber_Security_Business_Impact__c)),
        ISBLANK(Engagement__c ),
        ISBLANK(Text(Initial_AppSec_Applicability__c )),
        ISBLANK(Text(Initial_CI_Applicability__c)), 
        ISBLANK(TEXT( Initial_CI_HIPAA_Inherent_Risk__c )),
        ISBLANK(Text(Initial_Overall_TRO_Risk__c )),
        ISBLANK(Text(Initial_CI_PCI_Inherent_Risk__c )),
        ISBLANK(Text(Initial_Red_Team_Applicability__c)),
        ISBLANK(Text(Initial_Security_Arch_Applicability__c)),
        ISBLANK(Text(Initial_Vendor_Applicability__c )),
        ISBLANK(Text(Initial_Vendor_Inherent_Risk__c )),
        ISBLANK(Project__c), 
        ISBLANK(Text(Project__r.BE_Alignment__c )),
        ISBLANK(Project__r.BE_Conclusion__c),
        ISBLANK(Text(Project__r.BE_Team__c )),
        ISBLANK(Project__r.Engagement__c ),
        ISBLANK(Text(Project__r.Following_SDLC__c )),
        ISBLANK(Project__r.Need_By_Date__c),
        ISBLANK(Text(Project__r.Pilot_or_Poc__c )),
        ISBLANK(Project__r.Project_Description__c),
        ISBLANK(Project__r.Project_Expected_Go_Live_Date__c),
        ISBLANK(Project__r.Project_Manager__c ),
        ISBLANK(Project__r.Regions__c ),
        ISBLANK(Project__r.Requestor__c)
    )
)
```

Comment: I made the change and it saved thanks! but when i went to test the rule, it did not display when i didnt fill out several of the fields. Do you know why it would do that?

Comment: take the updated code, all the ISBLANK() condition should be in the OR condition

Comment: Like this OR(Engagement__c ),
        OR(Text(Initial_AppSec_Applicability__c )),

Comment: use my code, it will work

Comment: I used your code but the validation error didnt show up. It let me save the record and didnt say you need to fill out fields based on that

Comment: rather than writing entire logic, first check with one field and gradually write validation rule for all other fields, like `AND(
    Submitted_SDM_REVIEW__c  = TRUE , 
    ISBLANK(TEXT(Cyber_Security_Business_Impact__c))
)`